# Mobile Web - Share a custom text in Social Media

Tags: jquery, facebook, spring, share, spring-social

In a Spring mvc mobile web app i need to share a custom message to social media page 
that is facebook, twiter and linked In. I have tried fb Share button but its posting links only.

How do I add a predefined message to the post, e.g. "I have received the ticktes"

I don't want to use "ADD THiS" like third party tools. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: According to Facebook Platform Policy you are not allowed to prefill.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Spring Social?  It handles the authentication piece as well as provides an API for interacting with most social networks.  You can read more about it here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/

Answer (score 1):

as someone else points out, you can't pre-fill with the share button. However, you can give a try to the share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog